# Node.Js write and read Array to/from File

Tags: node.js, arrays, file-writing

i have a NodeJs applet that I want to save the Users Array (Contains Objects) to a File, I am doing this with:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');
fs.writeFileSync('data/inventur_users.json', util.inspect(users), 'utf-8');
```

The Output in the File inventur_Users.json is:

```
[ BU4AFLx3cUYqdjvYPci7: { id: '5LkOWtVFcqz29UpsAAAC',
    name: 'p.langkau@scharr.de',
    rechte: 'vollzugriff',
    client_ID: 'BU4AFLx3cUYqdjvYPci7' } ]
```

Now I am Reading the file back in with this code:

```
filedata = fs.readFileSync('data/inventur_users.json', 'utf-8');
```

My Problem is that i only get a String and I don't know how to convert the String back to an Array that contains Objects.

Thanks in advance, Patrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Firstly**

```
[ BU4AFLx3cUYqdjvYPci7: { id: '5LkOWtVFcqz29UpsAAAC',
    name: 'p.langkau@scharr.de',
    rechte: 'vollzugriff',
    client_ID: 'BU4AFLx3cUYqdjvYPci7' } ]
```

is not a valid json, you can verify it from here https://jsonlint.com/

Valid json would look like

```
[{
    "BU4AFLx3cUYqdjvYPci7": {
        "id": "5LkOWtVFcqz29UpsAAAC",
        "name": "p.langkau@scharr.de",
        "rechte": "vollzugriff",
        "client_ID": "BU4AFLx3cUYqdjvYPci7"
    }
}]
```

and then you can directly require content of `.json` file in a variable like

```
const filedata = require('data/inventur_users.json');
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, how can i convert an array to a json?
And if i Import the json, can i use it like i used the array?

Patrick

Comment: `[1, 2, 3]` is a valid json so you can store it directly in json file and while requiring it, yes you can use it directly like an array.
 You can use https://jsonlint.com/ to verify what is valid json and what is not

Comment: So i was able to export the Array to a valid Json, but if i want to import it with require i get this error: 'Error: Cannot find module 'data/inventur_users.json' but the json is in that directory

Comment: try with require('./data/inventur_users.json');

Comment: Now i can read the json but it gives me a string of the json without the " at the beginning and the end

Comment: what data were you storing ?
and you have to use JSON.stringify() before storing

Comment: I have a array of users that contains objects with the data of the user

users[object.client_ID] = ({
              'id': socket.id,
              'name': object.email,
              'rechte': 'vollzugriff',
              'client_ID': object.client_ID
            });

I save it with this line:

fs.writeFileSync('data/inventur_users.json', JSON.stringify(util.inspect(users)), 'utf-8');

The JSON File contains a valid JSON but when I import it with:     

var filedata = require('./data/inventur_users.json');      

I just get a String of the JSON without the leading and ending "

Comment: https://pastebin.com/nZqZNdpy
I pasted it here to make it a bit more clear

Comment: I already mentioned that 
`[ xBPTn9P3w10lH08otQoI: { id: '_MZgcFaySgbBE3OOAAAB',
    name: 'p.langkau@scharr.de',
    rechte: 'vollzugriff',
    client_ID: 'xBPTn9P3w10lH08otQoI' } ]` in you .json file is not valid json

I have pasted what a valid json will look like in my answer

Comment: In the JSON file there are leading and closing "
jsonlint.com says that it is a valid json.

Comment: data that you are writing into your .json file

`[ xBPTn9P3w10lH08otQoI: { id: '_MZgcFaySgbBE3OOAAAB',     name: 'p.langkau@scharr.de',     rechte: 'vollzugriff',     client_ID: 'xBPTn9P3w10lH08otQoI' } ]`

is not a valid json,
but when you put it using JSON.stringify(), it becomes a string which is valid string and valid json string but it is not an object

Comment: so data that you are storing should be like this

`[{
    "BU4AFLx3cUYqdjvYPci7": {
        "id": "5LkOWtVFcqz29UpsAAAC",
        "name": "p.langkau@scharr.de",
        "rechte": "vollzugriff",
        "client_ID": "BU4AFLx3cUYqdjvYPci7"
    }
}]`

Comment: Now i understood, but is there a option to convert an array to an objekt and not to a string?

Comment: the data that you are passing is neither an object nor an array (it is invalid)
but the correct format which I have shown you is array of objects, (array is itself an object subtype in javascript)

Comment: Now it makes sence, i changed the array to a object and removed the util.inspect from the file writer and now it works.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to convert the string back to a JavaScript object:

```
filedata = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('data/inventur_users.json', 'utf-8'));
```

You should also use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to save the file in the first place:

```
fs.writeFileSync('data/inventur_users.json', JSON.stringify(util.inspect(users)), 'utf-8');
```

Comment: I did it like in your example but filedata is still a string.

Comment: Have you also used `JSON.stringify(...)` to save the file?

Comment: Here you can see the code, json and output: https://pastebin.com/nZqZNdpy